# Reading a HTML file saved locally

Tags: python, html

I am looking to read a bunch of HTML files saved locally in C drive.

Error message -

" 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 248963: character maps to   "

I tried using BeautifulSoup library but getting an error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open("C:\Ada_Lovelace.html", "r")

soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Please help me with the optimized code.

Comment: Would you mind adding the error you get to the question ?

Comment: Your code is ok so the problem is probably that you have the wrong file path for the HTML file.

Comment: Add the full path to the `open`.

Comment: error message -  'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 248963: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

After adding "Unicode Transformation Format”, it worked.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open("C:\Ada_Lovelace.html", 'r', encoding="utf8")

soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```